# QProcess::waitForReadyRead for stderr?

Tags: qt, qprocess

Does `QProcess::waitForReadyRead` return when there is data in the process's stderr, or does it wait only on stdout? How can I wait for data on stderr without using signals and slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QProcess::setReadChannel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#setReadChannel)

Will control whether your monitoring stderr or stdout, so if you call:

```
myProcess->setReadChannel( QProcess::StandardError );
```

then `waitForReadyRead` will only act on stderr.

See also: [QProcess::setProcessChannelMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#setProcessChannelMode)